# mutations induced by transposons

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, homework, molecular-genetics

Question:

In contrast to chemically-induced mutations, mutations induced by transposons are more likely to ...

1. be lethal
2. de dominant
3. be stable
4. revert to wild types
5. be a gain of function

The answer is 4; but I have no understanding of why this is the correct answer, or, why the others answers are not correct.  Could someone help to explain why this is the case?

Comment: Transposons are mobile genetic elements, or jumping genes. If a Tn can jump into your gene then it can also often jump out again later, so sometimes the mutation reverts. This means the mutation is unstable, so 3. is incorrect. As an RFLP the Tn is dominant in a diploid, but usually a Tn mutation causes a recessive loss-of-function phenotype, so 2. and 5. are incorrect. In a diploid a recessive cannot be lethal on its own, because then it would be dominant, so 1. is incorrect.

Comment: @mdperry you can make that an answer. However, transposon can affect the X chromosome of the male and can show dominant effects. But since that is only a specific case we can dispose it.